# Define a custom has_many relation

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

Let's say an application has a `User` who can `Like` a `Post`. But also a `Post` can be owned by a `User` (on `owner_id`). So models would look like

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :likes
  has_many :posts, through: :likes
end

class Like < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :post
end

class Post < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :likes
  has_many :users, through: :likes
  belongs_to :owner, class_name: 'User'
end
```

How can I define a relation that would return all users with any correlation to a post?

So trying to replace the `users` association:

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  # no owner_id, lambda is called in an User::ActiveRecord_Relation context
  has_many :users, -> { where('users.id = ? OR likes.post_id = ?', owner_id, id) }, through: :likes

  # doesn't work because "Relation passed to #or must be structurally compatible."
  def users
    User.where(id: owner_id).or(users)
  end

  # works but isn't an association.
  def users
    User.joins(:likes).where('users.id = ? OR likes.post_id = ?', owner_id, id)
  end
end
```

I'd love to be able to define something that would allow me to write

`Post.includes(:users)`

without

```
ActiveRecord::AssociationNotFoundError: Association named 'users' was not found on Post; perhaps you misspelled it?
```

Comment: What's _any correlation to a post_? Doesn't `User.includes(:posts)` work?

Comment: No, because it includes only posts in relation through likes, not through the `owner_id` field.